# Perl unicode formatting issue

Tags: perl, unicode

Why doesn't this sample code work correctly?

```
#/usr/bin/perl

$a = "aaa%29";
$a =~ s/%/\\x/g;
print "a  $a \n";
$b = "aaa\x29";
print "b  $b \n";
$c = sprintf($a);
print "c  $c \n";
```

I want to get three times the same output line.

Comment: The code works correctly, but apparently you are expecting something strange. Which output line do you want, exactly? "aaa\x29" or "aaa)"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to decode URLs, as I guess, you should use the `uri_unescape` function from the `URI::Escape` module.

Or use something like `s{%([0-9A-F]{2})}{chr(hex($1))}egi`.

Comment: Good point about using pre-build modules for url/uri handling. Much less error-prone than hand-built regexes.

Answer (score 5):

For the first regexp, you could use:

```
$a = "aaa%29";
$a =~ s/%([0-9A-F]{2})/chr(hex($1))/gie;
print "a  $a \n";
```

I have no idea what you are trying to do with `sprintf` though.
(Turn on warnings in your code with either `use warnings;` or passing `-w` as an option to `perl`. The `sprintf` call is invalid.)

Comment: my first regexp was incomplete, would not match hex values correctly, only digits. corrected.

Comment: I think he was trying to get the `'aaa\x29'` (single quotes) to `"aaa\x29"` (double quotes) using the sprintf.

Comment: Now you're matching a bit too much. G-Z are not hexadecimal digits.

Comment: you're right, i was a bit lax in the checking :-) Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Yes, I expected getting something similar, but I haven't much experience in perl yet.

Answer (score 1):

'"','\','x','2','9','"' is Perl code for a string literal that creates a one-character string.

'\','x','2','9' is a different sequence, and it's never passed to the Perl parser, much less executed. Furthermore, `sprintf` doesn't treat "\" specially. All the escapes it knows start with "%".

That's why you're not getting the same output.